# Unable to access HTML from local folder on windows

Tags: html, image

What is wrong in the source field below ? I am just trying to display the image from my local system.

```
<img id="image1" src="file:///C:/cf-logo.jpg" class="img-polaroid"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets (images,css files,javascript files, etc) have to be in your web root (or below) in order to be viewable in a browser.

```
<!-- image is in the root web directory -->
<img id="image1" src="/cf-logo.jpg" class="img-polaroid"><br>
```

The only way to work around this is to call a server-side script that fetches the file and returns it for you.

```
<!-- image served by a script that can access the file directory -->
<img id="image1" src="/image.php?i=cf-logo.jpg" class="img-polaroid"><br>
```